# VB.NET Deserialize XML sub nodes by attribute text

Tags: vb.net, xml-deserialization

Trying to deserialize an XML file but having trouble with sub nodes.
I need to collect these by there ID value eg ConNum, class, recid.
Currently I can get one value back but it's giving me the name of the ID and not the value.
eg: xData.TRAN_DATEX.theTarget = ConNum where I require 20190910 instead.

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <targets>
    <target id="ConNum">20190910</target>
    <target id="class">Third</target>
    <target id="recid">123 </target>
  </targets>
```

Here's my class:

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

<Serializable, XmlRoot("targets")>
Public Class XmlFile
    <XmlElement("target")> Public Property TRAN_DATEX As myTarget
End Class

<Serializable, XmlRoot("target")>
Public Class myTarget
    <XmlAttribute("id")> Public theTarget As String

End Class
```

And here is the deserialize method:

```
Dim fFile As FileInfo = New FileInfo("C:\Temp\TARGETS.metadata")
Dim s As New XmlSerializer(GetType(XmlFile))
Using sr As New StreamReader(fFile.FullName)
    xData = s.Deserialize(sr)
    Stop
End Using
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`theTarget` is getting the value of the `id` attribute. You want the `XmlText` of that element:

```
<Serializable, XmlRoot("target")>
Public Class myTarget
    <XmlAttribute("id")> Public theTarget As String
    <XmlText> Public Property theValue As String
End Class
```

Then, instead of `xData.TRAN_DATEX.theTarget`, you can use `xData.TRAN_DATEX.theValue`

---

**Edit:** In response to the comment.

As there are multiple `<target>` elements, `TRAN_DATEX` will need to be a list:

```
<Serializable, XmlRoot("targets")>
Public Class XmlFile
    <XmlElement("target")> Public Property TRAN_DATEX As New List(Of myTarget)
End Class
```

LINQ can be used to access the data that is required:

```
Dim reqValueTarget = xData.TRAN_DATEX.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.theTarget = "ConNum")
If reqValueTarget IsNot Nothing then
    Dim reqValue = reqValueTarget.theValue
End If
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now. Is it possible though to get the value back by asking for ConNum?

Comment: Hopefully I have understood what you require. Please check the edited answer.